# Join/merge multiple JSON files into one file using Python 3.7

Tags: python, json, glob

I have multiple JSON files in a folder (~200) which I would like to combine and generate a single JSON file. I am trying following lines of code.

```
result = ''
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r", encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        result += infile.read()
        
with open("merged_file.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(result)
```

However, it generate the file with JSON content but all the content is in only one line. How can I append the content as it is in the files.

Comment: Simply concatenating multiple JSON objects will result in a non-JSON string. Do you mean to create a JSONL file, or a JSON file with an array of multiple objects?

Comment: I would like to have a . jsonl file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it by reading and parsing each JSON file, appending the parsed content to a list,

Example below:

```
json_objects = []

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    try:
        with open(f, "r", encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            file_content = json.load(infile)
            json_objects.append(file_content)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error {f}: {e}")

with open("merged_file.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_objects, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: It gives me this error: JSONDecodeError : Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Probably an issue with json file. I edited my answer and addd try except block. Run it and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :

```
import json
import glob

all_config = {}

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r", encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        json_content = json.load(infile)
        all_config.update(json_content)
        
        
with open("All.json", "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(json.dumps(all_config, indent=4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

hi run it and when done you can edit ALL_DATA._json -> ALL_DATA.json

```
import json
import glob

all_data = {}

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
with open(f, "r", encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    json_content = json.loads(infile.read())
    all_data.update(json_content)
    
    
with open("All_DATA._json", "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(json.dumps(all_data, indent=4)))
```